# como crear un button click para enlazar fragment a fragment, con plantilla navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, botón, click

Hola muy buenas hice una app con un navigation drawer con plantilla de android studio luego enlace los fragmentos con el navigation view,por ultimo cree un fragment inicio enlazado tambien.

Y ahora la cosa es que quiero poner esas mismas opciones y fragments del navigation view en el fragment inicio fragment_home.xml y fragment_home.java, para tener el menu de manera doble, esos mismos fragment enlazadosa botones en el fragment_home.

La cosa es que probé con codigo como el intent y nada, para como dentro del java del home cosas con findviewbyID me salian en rojo, probe otros códigos de aqui y nada y no sé tampoco si tendria que declararlo en androidmanifest.

Perdonar comentario anterior antes de la edición pero somos humanos y lo escribí desde la tableta la cual tiene algun problema con el teclado third party que le tengo, no me he dado cuenta hasta que habeis respondido, perdon y no ser tan duros, no he pegado codigo porque la verdad parece que ninguno de los que encontre funciona,no sé si seria mejor subiros unas captura

He probado los siguientes codigos tanto en Mainactivity.java como en fragment_home.java

**codigo 1
@Override
    public
    void onClick(View view) {
        Button button;
            // Get the view from fragment_home.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

```
        // Locate the button in content_main.xml
        button = findViewById(R.id.button4);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(fragment_home.this,
                        fragment_gallery.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

}
```

*codigo 2

button = view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    fragment_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           fragment_home fragment = new fragment_gallery();
           FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.replace(R.id.frame_home
,  fragment, "fragment_gallery");
           ft.addToBackStack(null);
           ft.commit();
        }
    });

**codigo 2:

Intent myintent = new Intent( getActivity() ,fragment_home.class);
 startActivity(fragment_gallery);
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_home, new Fragment_gallery);
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit a la transacción
 transaction.commit();

**codigo 3

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_home, new Fragment_gallery);
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit a la transacción
 transaction.commit();

Y nada. obviamente los puse ordenados y demas,no se que se me escapa

---

en estas caps vienen los codigos que intente y no funcionaron, tambien tengo la duda de si hacer el enlace aparte de en el fragment_home.xml si en el mainactivity.java o en el fragment_java. Pues lo que trato es de crear boton en fragment_home que al hacer click vaya por ejemplo a fragment_gallery.java es decir repetir lo del menu lateral en el fragment_home,el cual ya tengo cargado para que al abrir la app vaya directamente al mismo..Esa duda que comentaba es porque, aunque cada fragment tiene su java estan todos incluidos tambien en el mainactivity como menu lateral,de todos modos probe amnbos codigos que expongo tanto en mainactivity .java como en fragment_home.java
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@Override
    public
    void onClick(View view) {
        Button button;
            // Get the view from fragment_home.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

```
        // Locate the button in content_main.xml
        button = findViewById(R.id.button4);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(fragment_home.this,
                        fragment_gallery.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

button = view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    fragment_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           fragment_home fragment = new fragment_gallery();
           FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.replace(R.id.frame_home
,  fragment, "fragment_gallery");
           ft.addToBackStack(null);
           ft.commit();
        }
    });

Intent myintent = new Intent( getActivity() ,fragment_home.class);
 startActivity(fragment_gallery);

La forma correcta para cambiar un Fragmento es mediante FragmentTransaction:

Fragment nuevoFragmento = new BlankFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_home, new Fragment_gallery);
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit a la transacción
 transaction.commit();

Comment: Edita la pregunta para hacerla más clara, añade código...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tene en cuenta que no sabemos lo que estas haciendo, y tenes que ser claro con tu problema y con lo que necesitas. Agrega el codigo que probaste y no hizo lo que querias, y tambien un ejemplo claro de lo que necesitas.

Comment: El codigo debe ir como texto, las imagenes son muy dificiles de ver. Y solo incluye la parte del codigo que tiene que ver con la pregunta.

Comment: Mejore el codigo y ya da menos errores,tengo en fragment_home, lo siguiente:
como pongo el nuevo codigo?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, quitando imágenes y agregando solamente el código necesario para conocer tu error, también añade una buena descripción para conocer mejor a lo que te estas enfrentando, no olvides poner ademas errores generados.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día.

*Los Fragments* nos ayudan para aumentar la interacción en una misma pantalla.

> Crea una nueva instancia de los fragmentos, ejemplo:

Pon esto en tu fragmento

```
   public static Informacion newInstance() {

        Informacion f = new Informacion();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;  
}
```

Y esto en la clase principal donde harás el cambio

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag = null;
 frag =  Informacion.newInstance();
CambiarFragment(frag);
```

Usa un FrameLayout para intercambiar los fragmentos.

```
 public void CambiarFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag)
{
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            // Remplaza cualquier fragment que este en el contenedor

            transaction.replace(R.id.frameContent, frag); //frameContent es mi FrameLayout
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
}
```

Como ves, toda la interacción solo es una pantalla solo cambiamos entre ellas pero nos mantenemos en la misma Activity.

Citando a lo que dices:

> "Y ahora la cosa es que quiero poner esas mismas opciones y fragments
>   del navigation view en el fragment inicio fragment_home.xml y
>   fragment_home.java, para tener el menu de manera doble".

No es recomendable hacerlo, ya que cuentas con un menú que hace lo mismo, es repetitivo.

Answer (score -1):

disculpa no entendí muy bien tu pregunta pero si tienes un navegation_Drawer y quieres pasar a otro fragmento tienes que hacer eso:

```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId ();

            if (id == R.id.nav_logeo) {
                Frg_Logeo frg_logeo;
                frg_logeo = new Frg_Logeo ();
                getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().add ( R.id.content_main, frg_logeo ).commit ();

            }else if (id == R.id.nav_tecnica) {
                frg_tecnica = new Frg_Tecnica ();
                getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().add ( R.id.content_main, frg_tecnica ).commit ();

            }
```

---

Cuando agregas fragments también tienes que agregarlos en tu MainAcivity principal asi:

```
public class M_Menu extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,Fondo.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Frg_Logeo.OnFragmentInteractionListener,{
```

//cada fragmento que añadas, ir separandolos por "comas" y los activity, en el android manifest

---

// en tu onNavigationItemSelected, allí es el lugar donde puedes acceder a cada uno de tus item y el content_main, es el ID que le asignarás a tu XML principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si quieres con un botón a un fragment, hay varios casos:

1.- Pasar de un Fragmento a otro:

```
BCliente.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tabla_cliente= new Tbl_Cliente ();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, tbl_cliente);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            } 
);
```

2.- Pasar de un Frgamento a una Actividad:

```
BCliente.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PopUpTabla.class);
             startActivity(intent);

            }
        } );
```

---

Y por ultimo si estas dentro de un Frgamento no puedes utilizar un findviewbyID, en un fragmento debes primero hacer una vista y luego utilizarla, de ésta manera:

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    View w_logeo;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        w_logeo =inflater.inflate ( R.layout.frg__logeo, container, false );

       //cuando quieras instanciar una etiqueta lo haces así:
       Logi=(Button) w_logeo.findViewById ( R.id.btnlog );

       //Poner tu código acá dentro


        return w_logeo;
    }
```

Comment: me da replacefragment is never used

Comment: no me sale ahora me da error en el replaceFragment

Comment: En que parte te sale ese mensaje? ... cuando agregar fragment también tienen que añadirlo en un activity principal, lo editaré

Comment: Bloom la verdad es que no me sale y todo porque quiero hacer un app parecida a una que se llamama frases sacasticas en playstore, es decir solo quiero una cosa facil pero que es para alcanzar mas publicos un navigation drawer,no un fragment_home que es el que carga por defecto eso si lo consegui y en el xml del fragment_home botones grandes que enlacen a la vez a las actividades de la cortina izquierda asi de simple, creo que tengo varias cosas mal y asi mediante cosas cortas no puedo explicarlo bien,si hubiera otra forma.